# How to split area-spline area in different colors in c3js

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have c3js area-spline with one fill color that is working fine. I am trying to get color different for negative part of the chart, so area that is below 0 has one and above 0 another color. 
Also is there possibility to make another color on some custom region of the area let's say from 1 to 2 mark. Is that possible?

Comment: This does not seem to be possible. You may have a look at http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-regions option but it has very limited functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamically adjusted gradient as a fill

It does have a couple of knock-ons in terms of the points / legend colour (but these might be seen as being truer than a single colour). And you could always change those further on in the onrendered routine.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data2', 130, 100, -340, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        colors: {
            data2: 'url(#myGradient)',
        },
        type: 'area-spline'
    },
    oninit: function() {
        d3.select("svg defs").append("linearGradient")
          .attr("id", "myGradient")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("x2", 0)
          .attr("y1", 0)
          .attr("y2", 1)
          .html('<stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/><stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" class="changer"/><stop offset="50.01%" stop-color="blue" class="changer"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>')
      ;
    },
    onrendered: function () {
            // get the bbox for the series you're interested in
        var path = d3.select("g.c3-areas-data2 > path");
        var pbbox = path.node().getBBox();

        var y = this.y; // the chart's y scale
        var zeroPoint = y(0);   // where zero sits on the scale

                // work out where zero sits in relation/ratio to the bbox
        var pct = (zeroPoint - pbbox.y) / pbbox.height;
        pct *= 100;

                // set that as the new gradient stop
        d3.selectAll("#myGradient stop.changer").data([pct, pct + .01])
            .attr("offset", function(d) { return d+"%"; })
         ;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lcu7ce9/